# Active Directory cross forest group enumeration

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, domain

I have 2 active directory forests, each containing at least one domain but in both cases I am dealing with the top level domain.

I have a group on each domain, group1 (domain A) group2 (domain B). group1 in domain A has the group2 (from domain B) as a member.

Is it possible using "Active Directory Users and Computers" from a domain A member to enumerate the members of group2 from domain B. At present it only appears as an object in group1 and I can see what it is a member of but not the members contained in it.

Is this possible or must you enumerate the object via a domain member in domain B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WINS was required in the domain to enumerate this, the console was trying to enumerate it via TESTDOMAIN1\Group2. Once WINS was installed the members were available.

Comment: WINS? This can't be the correct solution, are you sure that the DNS servers in each domain have been correctly configured to query the other domain's DNS servers with a filter?

Comment: I believe that it was due to using the NETBIOS value rather than the FQDN for the domain. The only action was to install WINS and this solved the problem! Whether it is the "correct" solution is an exercise left to the reader :)

Answer (score 0):

You could re-focus-ize ADUC onto domain B, but the larger answer is that no, you can just "click through" using ADUC across forests. I went as far as to dump all our domains' memberships nightly to SQL so users can search to get complete group member lists that include all nesting.